# Django: filtering order_by a generic relation

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have two classes:

```
class Translation(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    field = models.CharField(max_length=64) #field from the translated model
    language = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=settings.LANGUAGES, verbose_name=_("language"))
    text = models.TextField() #translation

class Category(models.Model):
    translations = generic.GenericRelation(Translation)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name=_("Name"))
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, default="", verbose_name=_("Slug"))
```

Is there a way to order Categories by translation__text filtering the order_by by the current language? If I use

```
Category.objects.all().order_by("translations__text")
```

I get categories sorted by all translations, not just the current language. I guess, what I ned is filtering the order_by set somehow (to use only translations of a given language)? Is there a way to do so?

DB = PostgreSQL

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Category.objects.filter(translations__language='en').order_by("translations__text")
```

Comment: Almost. However, this solution returns duplicates that cannot be filtered with distinct() :-/

Answer (score 3):

Duplicates are unavoidable. It's a result of the SQL that Django generates for order by clauses over generic relations. See ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11387.

It has not been resolved even in trunk, and the ticket is 3 years old and hasn't been modified in 14 months, so I wouldn't hold my breath.

UPDATE ***
The referenced bug was fixed in early 2013 according to the referenced bug report https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11387. From my initial testing, it would appear that calling distinct() on the recommended answer in this post will return the correct queryset.

```
Category.objects.filter(translations__language='English').order_by('translations__text').distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

do u mean this?

```
Category.objects.filter(translations__language="English").order_by("translations__text")
```

Comment: yup, apart of duplicates it's a good solution. Any way to get rid of them?