# How to order_by generic relation in Django?

Tags: django, django-contenttypes

I am basically trying to do the opposite of what is described in this question: [Django: filtering order_by a generic relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737546/django-filtering-order-by-a-generic-relation)

```
class Translation(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    field = models.CharField(max_length=64) #field from the translated model
    language = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=settings.LANGUAGES, verbose_name=_("language"))
    text = models.TextField() #translation

class Category(models.Model):
    translations = generic.GenericRelation(Translation)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name=_("Name"))
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, default="", verbose_name=_("Slug"))
```

I would like to retrieve all Translations and order by Category name. Something like this:

```
Translation.objects.all().order_by('object__name')
```

But this doesn't work because `object` isn't a column in the database. Trying to order by `content_type__name` also doesn't work.

Comment: What if there is another class like Category2 which has also translations as a genericrelation but it doesn't have column 'name'. Do you want these objects too when you call order_by('object__name')?

Comment: A good point. My desired functionality wouldn't be very reusable in other apps, but fortunately for my project I would never have a class related to Translation that didn't have a name field.

Comment: Then I recommend you to use not GenericForeignKey, but a simple ForeignKey. You can use this manual https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967574/django-order-by-generic-foreign-key) asked an identical question but discovered it's simply not possible. Unfortunately, it looks like you'll need to use `raw()` to construct the SQL query manually.

Answer (score 0):

in category you need to create a related query name like...

```
class Category(models.Model):
    translations = generic.GenericRelation(Translation, related_query_name='category')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name=_("Name"))
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, default="", verbose_name=_("Slug"))
```

Then you can make a query like
`Translation.objects.all().order_by('category__name')`